# Safari not persisting HTTP only cookie between in app browsers and safari browser app

Tags: javascript, ios, cookies, safari, httpcookie

I am sending a http-only cookie after a user logs in. This cookie is attached to every subsequent request and the API calls are getting authorized correctly.

The issue arises in the following scenario:

1. Share a link to my website on slack/WhatsApp. Open the link from one of these apps. This will be opened in their in-app browsers
2. Login successfully.
3. Now if I open the same website link in the Safari browser app, it asks for login again and the http-only cookie is not persisted.

Is there anyway to persist the cookie across safari instances?